# tumblr pages with lots of images in a single page crashes chrome

Tags: google-chrome, memory

When I load a tumblr page with lots of images on a single page, scrolling down image after image, after some hundreds of images my ram (4gb) is quite full and google chrome crashes.

Is there is a way to configure chrome such as it doesn't keep in memory ALL the image loaded in the page but only the last (for example) 50?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it will help but here [Autoit](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) script what will "reduce" working set memory chrome processes.

After install [Autoit](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/) and [Editor](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/). Right click on desktop->New->Autoit Script. Right click on this created file->Edit. Now you should see ScITE window and after line "Add your code below here" add this code:

```
while 1
    Sleep(60000*5);reduce memory every 5 minutes
$aProcessList=ProcessList("chrome.exe")
For $i = 1 To $aProcessList[0][0]
_ReduceMemory($aProcessList[$i][1])
Next
WEnd

Func _ReduceMemory($i_PID = -1)

    If $i_PID <> -1 Then
        Local $ai_Handle = DllCall("kernel32.dll", 'int', 'OpenProcess', 'int', 0x1f0fff, 'int', False, 'int', $i_PID)
        Local $ai_Return = DllCall("psapi.dll", 'int', 'EmptyWorkingSet', 'long', $ai_Handle[0])
        DllCall('kernel32.dll', 'int', 'CloseHandle', 'int', $ai_Handle[0])
    Else
        Local $ai_Return = DllCall("psapi.dll", 'int', 'EmptyWorkingSet', 'long', -1)
    EndIf

    Return $ai_Return[0]
EndFunc;==> _ReduceMemory()
```

Then in SciTE window press Tools->Build. Now you will get executable in same directory where was Autoit script. Run this executable(.exe). In tray will Autoit icon on right click you can exit script.

Another way from google:

[Tab Memory Purge Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-memory-purge/aclmceilickagfkaddbiedcnccdkfafa/)